# How do i get my program to register the second error in my try/catch program

Tags: c++, debugging, try-catch, computer-science

I am new to C++. I have a try/catch program but, whenever I try to test the second catch block to see if it catches its related throw statement, the program prints the message from the first catch block. This is the code:

I have tried to change the specific error (something like `std::invalid_argument`) to something more general like `std::exception` but that wasn’t specific enough for my error message. This is for a class and the code must account for user input that isn't a number, or isn't a number 1-4.

```
//c++

/*For context, choice is an integer from
User input that is supposed to be a number 1-4.*/

void search() {
    int choice;
    std::cout << "Search by:\n1:Title\n2:Year\n3:Actor\n4:Rating\n";
    
    try {
        std::cin >> choice;
        if(!isdigit(choice)) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Please type a number. \n");
        } 
        if(choice >= 5 || choice <= 1) {
            throw out_of_range("Please input a number between 1 and 4");
        }
    }
    catch(std::out_of_range const& e){
        std::cout << e.what();
        cin.clear();
    }
    catch(std::invalid_argument const& e) {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
```

Sorry if it"s not the best, I am still learning.

The issue is that the `out_of_range` catch statement does not print its error message when it is thrown. I only get the invalid_argument throw/catch response.

Comment: _"isn't working"_ isn't a sufficient problem description. [Edit] your question and elaborate please.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
if(!isdigit(choice)) {
```

doesn't do what you think it does. It returns whether a character code such as `'x'` (`120` in ASCII) or `'4'` (`52` in ASCII) is a digit or not. (i.e. it returns true for all character codes between `'0'` and `'9'`).  But `choice` does not represent a character code, it represents the number that the user typed in integer form.

If I'm not mistaken, `choice` will be `0` if what's typed isn't a valid integer. In which case, you can keep your code simply as:

```
    try {
        std::cin >> choice;
        if(choice >= 5 || choice <= 1) {
            throw out_of_range("Please input a number between 1 and 4");
        }
    }
    catch(std::out_of_range const& e){
        std::cout << e.what();
        cin.clear();
    }
```

Comment: C++11 `choice` would have garbage.  Later C++ fixed that.  Also may need to `cin.ignore` or the bad stuff may still be cobbing up the input.

Comment: In your answer, you wrote: "If I'm not mistaken, `choice` will be `0` if what's typed isn't a valid integer." -- You are not mistaken, according to [this documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt). I believe that @Eljay is correct that this is guaranteed since C++11, although the documentation does not state this.